# Can't get Mongoose with discriminator to work

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

My problem is, I defined a base/parent Schema and 3 children schema but I only get

> No overload match this call

Here is my schema

```
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';

export interface IBaseCriteria {}

const baseOptions = {
  discrimatorKey: 'itemType',
  collection: 'criterias',
};
const baseCriteriaSchema = new Schema<IBaseCriteria>({
  baseOptions,
});

export default model<IBaseCriteria>('BaseCriteria', baseCriteriaSchema);
```

```
import { model, Schema } from "mongoose";
import BaseCriteria from "./baseCriteria.model";

export interface IDateCriteria {
after: Date;
before: Date;
}

const dateCriteria = BaseCriteria.discriminator(
"date",
new Schema({
 after: { type: Date },
 before: { type: Date },
})
);

export default model("DateCriteria", dateCriteria);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`.discriminator` returns a model. So you don't need create a model.

Your `dateCriteria` already is a model.

---

Just export using:

```
export default dateCriteria
```

---

Look in discriminator documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html

> It returns a model whose schema is the union of the base schema and the discriminator schema.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, Do I still need to type with my interface the discriminator and/or new Schema methods ?

Comment: Yeap. Use `const dateCriteria = BaseCriteria.discriminator<IDateCriteria>(.......)`